# Supporting multiple screens - wrong layout is picked by device

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

i got to the point in the app where i need to make layout adjustments for multipule screen.
these are the folders i have for layouts:
(each has a landscape version as well)
layout 
layout-800x480
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw800dp

most of them work fine, the problem is with the main layout folder.
when i run the app on a Galaxy S3 or Nexus 4, the device picks the 800x480 layout, altough these devices have bigger resolution. so the main layout is never picked..
if i understand correctly, a folder such as "layout-800x480" is supposed to be only for devices with the exact same resolution.. am i wrong?

Comment: check your android manifeast file

Comment: what should i look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the only valid specifiers (resolution wise) for the folders name are:

- Smallest screen width (ie: sw600dp)
- Available screen width (ie: w600dp)
- Available screen height (ie: h600dp)

So that would explain why the layout-800x480 folder is being ignored

Comment: That name was given by the eclipce's android-layout-wizard, so i beleive it is correct. and as i said, this folder is not being ignored, the main layout folder is.

Answer (score 0):

Different layout folder

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

add the following code into your manifeast file

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
          android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
          android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
          android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

for more information [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: thanks, but the problem for me is that the "normal screen size" contains a variety of sizes. for example - galaxy s2 and s3, are both normal screen sized, but the galaxy s3 is much bigger and can contain more..